# Можно ли как-то получить прямой эфир через вебкамеру?

Tags: java, web-camera

Мне нужны ссылки, примеры кода, как получать данные с веб камеры пк в наст.время

Comment: Куда и для каких целей вы хотите его получить? От этого может зависеть способ получения

Comment: я давно находил код открытия прямого эфира с веб камеры на java, но тогда, я не смог найти в интернете нужные мне библиотеки. Это приложение у меня как проект в моем институте, я делаю прогу по типу скайпа/дискорда, и я выбрал такой способ реализации(через прямой эфир вебкамеры)